# How to parse an IPv4 packet header in Python

Tags: python, casting

I have some code in C that looks similar to this:

```
struct iphdr{
#if __BYTE_ORDER == __LITTLE_ENDIAN
  unsigned int ihl:               4;
  unsigned int version:           4;
#elif __BYTE_ORDER == __BIG_ENDIAN
  unsigned int version:           4;
  unsigned int ihl:               4;
#else
  #error "Please fix <bits/endian.h>"
#endif
  uint8_t tos;
  uint16_t tot_len;
  uint16_t id;
  uint16_t frag_off;
  uint8_t ttl;
  uint8_t protocol;
  uint16_t check;
  uint32_t saddr;
  uint32_t daddr;

};
...
...
...
unsigned char * ip_header_bytes = "\x45\x00\x00\xf8\xb8\xa7\x00\x40\x06\x81\x80\xac\x10\x44\x03\x22\x78\xed\x4c";
struct iphdr * ipdata = (struct iphdr *)ip_header_bytes;
```

And with that snippet I could access the various members within `ipdata`.

Now say I have a Python class that contains similar data to `iphdr` and I have a variable that contains the same data as `ip_header_bytes`. Is there a way I can populate a new instance of `iphdr` with the data from `ip_header_bytes`?

Comment: No, not really. Casting as such doesn't really exist in Python, which is a much higher-level language than C. Of course, you can parse that data and create the instance

Comment: But if you provide a [mcve] we could suggest an approach

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Is there some sort of work around I can use?

Comment: Again, you *really must* provide a [mcve]

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yeah I saw your second comment the moment I clicked add comment

Comment: That cast doesn't have defined behaviour in C.

Comment: @ikegami Does this make using it bad practice?

Comment: Relying on [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) is just plain wrong. In theory, anything can happen, including crashing your program. In practice, it's happens to be pretty predictable for some compiler-platform combos. (e.g. I can tell you exactly what it does with gcc on x86 or x86-64.) But it's not portable, and it *can* crash on the program on some platforms in practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C code relies on undefined behaviour. It doesn't have a predictable result. But you don't really care about that. What you're really asking is how to parse the header of an IPv4 packet.

First of all, an IPv4 packet header is 20 bytes long, and you only have 19.

Once you resolve that, you'd use `struct.unpack` to convert the bytes into numbers.

```py
import struct

header_packed = b"...20 bytes..."
header_values = struct.unpack( ">BBHHHBBHII", header_packed )
```

The first two bytes each consist of two fields, so you'll need to follow up with bit operations to extract these.

```py
ihl     = header_values[0] >> 4;
version = header_values[0] & 0xF;

dscp    = header_values[1] >> 2;
ecn     = header_values[1] & 0x3;
```

And if you want ip address objects from the last two fields, you can use

```py
import ipaddress

saddr = ipaddress.ip_address( header_values[8] )
daddr = ipaddress.ip_address( header_values[9] )
```

Creating a `struct`-like object in Python from the tuple and these extracted fields is left to you.